# Is it possible to use flume as kafka producer for log ingestion?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

I have a task of configuring a simple pipeline for app log ingestion.
A prerequisite for this pipeline is to use kafka as the transport protocol.
As I understand, flume has a built-in capability of ingesting log files.
Is there a way to use flume as a producer, and have it pass its output onto a kafka topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Flume as a producer for Kafka.
Have a look at this API provided by Flume: https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.6.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/sink/kafka/KafkaSink.html

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use. As specified in the previous response.

Just want to add that you need to make configurations similar to:

```
# Sources, channels, and sinks are defined per
# agent name, in this case flume1.
flume1.sources  = kafka-source-1
flume1.channels = hdfs-channel-1
flume1.sinks    = hdfs-sink-1

# For each source, channel, and sink, set
# standard properties.
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.zookeeperConnect = ...
```

Comment: This configuration utilizes Kafka as Source and HDFS as Sink, while  the OP is asking for *Kafka as Sink*.